# Parsing dict in Python

Tags: python

I have this dictionary, with some code to print from it:

```
fichiers_dict= {
    'sample1':{'libelle':'sample1.csv','server':'10.21.11.41'},
    'sample2':{'libelle':'sample2.csv','server':'192.168.1.40'},
    'sample3':{'libelle':'sample3.csv','server':'10.21.7.251'},
    'sample4':{'libelle':'sample4.csv','server':'10.21.12.200'} 
    }

 for serveurs in fichiers_dict:
    for fichier in fichiers_dict[serveurs]:
        print(fichiers_dict[serveurs][fichier]['libelle'])
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What are you trying to do? what is the expected output?

Comment: `for sample in fichiers_dict.values(): print(sample['libelle'])`…

Comment: You're using one subscript too many, there's no such thing as `fichiers_dict['sample1']['libelle']['libelle']` The first for-loop is going to iterate over each subdict in the dict. But the second for-loop is going to iterate over each key in the subdict: 'libelle' and 'server', and return you a string. Then you try to index into a string with `['libelle']`, which makes no sense, as your error is telling you.

Answer (score 3):

```
for serveurs in fichiers_dict: # keys of fichiers_dict
    for fichier in fichiers_dict[serveurs]: # keys of fichiers_dict[serveurs]
        print(fichiers_dict[serveurs][fichier]['libelle']) # key(string)['libelle'] -> wrong
```

As I added in comments, when you iterate directly on dict, its the keys getting iterated.
So `fichiers_dict[serveurs][fichier]` is the key `libelle`.

If you again to sub-index of the string `libelle`, it cannot be a string index, but only integer.

```
for serveurs in fichiers_dict.values():
    print(serveurs['libelle'])
```

should be enough.

Comment: Yes that's what I expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print values with Key - 'libelle'

```
fichiers_dict= {
    'sample1':{'libelle':'sample1.csv','server':'10.21.11.41'},
    'sample2':{'libelle':'sample2.csv','server':'192.168.1.40'},
    'sample3':{'libelle':'sample3.csv','server':'10.21.7.251'},
    'sample4':{'libelle':'sample4.csv','server':'10.21.12.200'} 
    }

for key, value in fichiers_dict.items():
    print(value['libelle'])
```

Comment: What I want is to loop like foreach function in PHP for creating user in a csv file

Comment: Please be more specific!